# Change colour and size of a certain string in a textblock (Windows Phone 7) in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, textblock

Hi I have a button (btnAdd) that adds the content of a textbox (txtName) to a textblock (lblName). I want to add a date to the textblock when btnAdd is pressed but I want it to be a different font size and colour. So far my code looks like

```
lblName.Text = txtName.Text " " + DateTime.Now
```

I only want DateTime.Now to be a different size and colour. Is this possible?

EDIT: Instead of a label I need to display it in a listBox
 my new code that I need help on is:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(txtName.Text " " + DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to assign `Inlines` rather than `Text`:

```
lblName.Inlines.Clear();
lblName.Inlines.AddRange(new Inline[]
{
    new Run(txtName.Text + " ")
    {
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black)
    },
    new Run(DateTime.Now.ToString())
    {
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Green)
    }
});
```

You can (and should) also bind to Run's directly from XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" />
        <Run Text=" " Foreground="Black" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Now}" Foreground="Green" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: If I do it the xaml way as you have suggested, How do I set the text when the button is pressed?

Comment: Hi The requirements for my project have changed. I now need it to add in a listbox rather than a label. Can this still be done?

Comment: The binding of Runs is still relevant even from within a DataTemplate